# How I can create a Spring Boot rest api to pull the specific repository branches from GitLab by using GitLab's API?

Tags: spring-boot, merge, gitlab, branch, gitlab-api

I want to design a Spring Boot REST API using GitLab's  API to pull the specific repository branches from GitLab.

### Requirement

We have been working on a big project and that project functionality is getting split into nearly 15 microservices and we have a GitLab repository for each microservice to organise the code remotely. And each repository has many branches like

1. master branch
2. dev branch
3. prod branch

And when we do have a prod release by that time we are raising merge request from dev branch to prod branch by logging into GitLab. And same practice we are doing for all other microservices which need prod deployments. So, here we think rather logging into gitlab and raising merge request from one branch to another branch every time.. we would like to write some Spring Boot service which consumes GitLab services like pulling specific repo details like its branches and other info and then raise merge request from one branch to another branch

So here we mainly looking for two operations one is pull the repository branch details and once pull the branches then raise a merge request from one branch to another branch.

- Pull repository branches
- Make branch merge request

And we are ready with React UI at client side and looking at REST services with above operations.

As I haven't worked before on such API implementations, I am interested in how achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into the use of Spring's RestTemplate from the spring-boot-starter-web project.  You can use the RestTemplate to call the GitLab APIs to perform your operations on each of the repositories.

Now, there is a lot of information on this subject and a full write-up would be enormous so my suggestion would be to read through Spring's guide on building REST APIs.  Baeldung also has a nice little introduction to the rest template that can be found at https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: thanks for your response and here my actual issue with how we can consume gitlab services from restapi and initial configurations for same. And I do have good experience on springboot microsservices. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent.  Then I think you only need to reference the GitLab API documentation.  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/api_resources.html

Comment: yeah I am looking such a reference, thank you much hsoj48. I will try and let you know.